# Can't enable bluetooth on Win10 Enterprise x64 (HP Pavilion 17)

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth

I was working on this system this morning when my BT mouse stopped responding. I went to check settings>Bluetooth and Other Devices (the windows store/Metro app) and found the BT option missing. Then I went to services and found all BT-related services to be disabled, so I started them. Finally, I opened device manager and saw a curious thing; the mainboard BT adapter disappeared approximately every 500ms and reappeared 500ms later. I tried rebooting and reinstalling the BT driver (Intel Wireless Bluetooth) but nothing helped, although it reinstalled cleanly.

Additional info; about 1/3 the time the BT driver icon has a triangle with an exclamation point on it when it reappears. Also, the hardware tab under device properties for the BT adapter is completely blank.

Comment: Maybe the BT adapter is glitched - try another one.

Comment: Except it's the one on the mobo. If it persists I will buy a usb one.

Answer (score 0):

This is too weird and may indicate a hardware problem.

I suggest to buy or loan an external BT adapter.
Use Device Manager to disable the glitched one.
If this works correctly then you have your answer.

Best to avoid playing too much with Windows setup if the problem is really hardware.